# Displaying a Promt on New Tab or Blank Page on Bookmarklet Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prompt, bookmarklet

I am unable to get the prompt to display from New Tab or Blank Page. Is there a way to do this?

Bookmarklet:

```js
javascript:
(function() { 
    var val= prompt("Enter Phone Number",""); 
    if (val) 
        location="https://officesite.com/phonenumber/value="+escape(val);
})()
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: For me it works from a blank about (`about:blank`). It's only on the New Tab page that it doesn't work. Am I understanding the question right? You have a bookmarklet and it works on most pages but not New Tab (and, for you apparently, blank)?

Comment: Chrome version 50.0.2661.94 m (64-bit) also supports new tab page situation. Try updating your browser and run again.

Comment: @yılmaz: Chrome v50 is markedly out of date. The current version is v58, and the bookmarklet doesn't work on the New Tab page.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes you are right but question owner might want to let it run in spite of not having latest version.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yuup, you'r right

Comment: @yılmaz i think i have to downgrade my chrome, on v50 it works properly if i run from new tab.
Thanks all.

Comment: @Randy Maulana so upvote please ;)

Comment: according to this site https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy it was done on purpose.  "alert()/confirm()/prompt() dialogs have changed from being app-modal to being dismissed when their tab is switched from. This change took place across all channels at the beginning of May 2017."